# SQL Server query running slow I need help optimizing it to improve performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization

I have this SQL Server query, it is running really slow, I need to improve the performance of it, any advise would be helpful.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.projid),
    a.Id, a.Company, a.ProjectType, a.ProjectSize, 
    a.ProjectIdNumber, a.Location, a.ProjectOwner,
    a.Description, a.Purpose, a.ProjectName,
    a.ProjectCategory, a.AssetType, a.department,
    CONCAT(c.LedgerCode,'_','CX','_',a.ProjectIdNumber) AS ProjectID,
    a.status, a.approved,   
    a.AmountRequested, a.EmissionReduction, a.EmissionReporting,
    a.WasteCostImpact, a.WasteType, a.WasteUom,
    a.WaterCostImpact, a.WaterUom, a.wastesavings, 
    a.EnergyType, a.EnergyConsumption, a.EnergyUom,
    a.EnergyCostImpact, a.EmissionSavings, a.DraftDate, 
    a.FiscalYearEnd, a.FiscalYearStart, a.SubmittedDate, 
    a.EHSProject, a.energysavings, a.WaterSavings, 
    a.GTO, a.GTOAmount, a.MPGT, a.AnnulizedEbitdaSavings, 
    a.ProjectInternalID,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.economiclife IS NULL 
            THEN 16 
            ELSE a.economiclife 
    END As Economic_Life, 
    a.capx_summary_id,
    CAST(b.Actual AS int) Actual, 
    b.Months, b.Spend,b.[Year]
FROM 
    CapXProject a 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ID, [year], ProjId,Actual, Months, Spend,
         capx_summary_id
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              ID, projid, [year], actual, m1 June, m2 July,
              m3 August, m4 September, m5 October, m6 November, 
              m7 December, m8 January, m9 February, m10 March,
              m11 April, m12 May, capx_summary_id
          FROM 
              CapXFiscalYearSpend) Monthly_Spend
    UNPIVOT
        (Spend FOR Months IN 
    (June,July,August,September,October,November,December,January,February,March,April,May)
    )   AS Unpivot_Months  
    ) AS b ON a.Id = b.ProjId
    --WHERE a.Status >= 0 and a.Status <=8
    --WHERE a.Status IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN  
    Master_Company c ON a.Company = c.Id
WHERE 
    a.ProjectType <> 2
    AND a.FiscalYearEnd <> 0
    AND a.FiscalYearEnd >= b.Year
```

Comment: What hardware (CPU, RAM, Storage) and operating system are you running, which RDBMS are you using, how long does this query take to run, and what is the number of rows and size of data in the table?

Comment: 32GB RAM, 476 GB Storage, SQL Server, query takes 1 Minute 15 Seconds to RUN, 212,473 rows

Comment: take every query optimize it, see if you can omit solme column. even ten with knowing your tables and an EXPLAIN/analyse or query plan it is impossible to tell you something

Comment: Do you *need* that `DISTINCT`? It's an expensive operator and usually, with that many columns, suggests a logic flaw.

Comment: Your aliasing doesn't make a lot of sense here either. `a` for `CapXProject`? Why not `CXP`? Use *meaningful* aliases; it makes it much easier for you and others to read your SQL. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: `DISTINCT(b.projid)` doesn't make sense, `DISTINCT` is not a function, instead it acts like a `GROUP BY` over all the columns. Most likely you have some logical flaw in your joins causing duplicate rows, you should probably fix that.

Comment: Without the definition of your tables, indexes and a query plan for this query it is impossible to say